# django database bug inccorect printing choice field

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

so i am trying to take data from admin panel and one field is choice field (male and female).
when i registered users with female and male type in my dashboard everyone have only 1 value
which is female so i need to fix it but how i dont know here is my code about views models and dashboard.

models.py

```
class Id(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)

    CHOICES = [('Male', 'Female'),
               ('Female', 'Male')]
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=30, choices=CHOICES)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.first_name
```

this is views

```
def home(request):
    context = {
        'posts': Id.objects.all(),
        'title': 'Home'
    }
        return render(request, 'blog/home.html', context)


def about(request):
    return render(request, 'blog/about.html', {'title': 'About'})
```

and last this is my home.html (dashboard where all my users data will showing up

```
{% extends 'blog/base.html' %}

{% block content %}
    {% for post in posts %}
        <article class="media content-section">
          <div class="media-body">
            <div class="article-metadata">
              <a class="mr-2" href="#">{{ post.first_name }}</a>
            </div>
            <p class="article-content">{{ post.gender}}</p>
          </div>
        </article>
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock content %}
```

Comment: Your choice pairs are crossed over.

Comment: Hello @luka how your are saving user can you provide code how you did it?

Comment: from admin panel statically

Comment: @KlausD. yes i know but not working other way i changed it like this but in my admin panel showing like this  CHOICES = [('Male', 'Female'),('Male', 'Female')] in panel is like female female

Comment: @luka make your choices `CHOICES = [('Female', 'Female'), ('Male', 'Male')]` .